# SQL Server logs empty?

Tags: sql-server

In the SQL Server Management Studio in **Management** I can view the **SQL Server Logs**.

I "inherited" a server where this Log is always empty. I'd guess my predecessor somehow disabled the SQL Server Log.

How do I enable this Log again?

Comment: I'm not following you. What version/edition of SQL are you working with? Are you referring to the SQL Server Configuration Manager? Are you referring to Shared Memory, Named Pipes, TCP/IP, and VIA?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I refer to SQL Server Management Studio (at least that's the name in the german edition). I wrote "tools" above. It's SQL Server 2005, but I guess the source would be the same for 2008.

Comment: Here, this software I refer to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio - it is contained in the SQL Server package as optional install.

Comment: Here's a screen cap of mine, where are you having the problem? http://i1195.photobucket.com/albums/aa384/RateControl/SSMS.png

Comment: Ah, ok, the menu item is called "management > SQL Server logs" in the english version (I guessed my translation wrong). Thanks!!